# What CAD software has a good variety of materials and includes a good suite of stress calculations?

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, cad

I'm new to most **CAD** work. I'm in the process of designing a **floating structure** that will include cement ballast, titanium or other seawater inert structural material, fiberglass with resin, etc.

I've already done some modeling and calculated capsizing forces. I do not have a way to calculate if the structure is strong enough to hold together.

The **stresses** I need to test for are those that would be generated by category 5+ storms on the open ocean.

Any **software recommendations** would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a budget in mind?  Are you looking for a free solution or paid?

Comment: No budget in mind. Obviously, less expensive is better than more if it gets the job done without much additional work. I'm not looking to spend more than $200 bucks. If that means I need to find someone to share license costs with I'm willing.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by issuing a disclaimer:

I am biased in that I retired from CNC Software, the developer of [Mastercam](https://www.mastercam.com/).  It's a paid CAD/CAM solution used by majors corporations.  However, it does offer many different solutions to meet your needs.

On the free end, there's Autodesk [Fusion 360](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/overview) that I currently use for 3D printing.

I'm not sure whether either solution will address your concerns for “stress” calculations.

Comment: Fusion 360 is not necessarily free.

Comment: @EricS That's true, but, the version I use is free.

Comment: It was free for me for a year and then it wasn’t. I’m just suggesting that your answer saying Fusion 360 is free isn’t accurate. You could say that it’s free to use in certain circumstances and direct the reader to its website for details.